# Remote desktop only connecting to some computers within a network

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, desktop, remote

I've been having some issues with Remote Desktop Connections, and I can't seem to find an answer after googling and looking through previous threads. Hoping to hear everyone's thoughts on what I may be missing out on.

**Situation**

There are 5 computers within my work place - 
(all on Windows 7, SP 1)

- Desktop (**D**), connected via LAN cable
- Spare laptop (**S**), connected to wifi
- Laptop 1,2,3 (**1**,**2**,**3**), connected via LAN cable and wifi

I hope to remotely control the desktop unit **D** from the Spare unit **S**, but when I try to I encounter the standard error: "Remote Desktop can't connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons". I am able to remotely connect to **D** using Laptops **1-3**, but unfortunately these 3 laptops are often used for other reasons so I would still need to use **S** most of the time.

Between Laptops **1-3** and **S**, **S** seems to be able to remotely connect to laptop **3**, but the same error appears for laptops **1** and **2**.

Connecting from **D** to the other units, the standard error appears in each scenario. I find this strange but it's not important; I do not have to remotely control the laptops from my desktop.

When I try to ping the various units, this was what I observed.

- **S** ping to **D** : timed out
- **1,2,3** ping to **D**: 0% lost
- **S** ping to **1**: 0% lost
- **S** ping to **2**: timed out
- **S** ping to **3**: 0% lost

In the other direction,

- **D** ping to **1**,**3**: 0% lost
- **D** ping to **2**: timed out
- **D** ping to **S**: timed out

Hope the information is relevant. Would appreciate advice on how I may get **S** to remotely connect with **D**, or an explanation on why it may not be possible to accomplish what I hope to do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to get a better picture, what is your network topology? Routers, gateway, firewall, switches, wires no where? With pings failing it sounds like networking issues. Get those solved and move to the rdp issues.

Comment: What Operating systems are you running on all 5 computers?

Comment: @jharrell I'm not too sure about the network topology as I'm not the network administrator. But if laptops **1, 2 & 3** can connect to **D**, I'm guessing there aren't any network issues. All the laptops were set up in the same way; no special firewalls or restrictions. Although if there is something you think may be causing the problem, do let me know how to check it!

Comment: @NetworkKingPin The OS on all 5 computers are Windows 7, SP 1.

Comment: And do you have remote access setup on all 5? As it is not set by default when using them. Just want to rule that out.

Comment: What are the antivirus programs and firewalls on each of these systems?

Comment: @NetworKingPin Yup, remote acces is enabled on all 5. I've tried setting **D** to "Allow connections from computer running any version of Remote Desktop" as well, it still didn't work

Comment: @jharrell Being organizational laptops/PCs they're all running the same antivirus and firewalls, Trend Micro OfficeScan and Windows Firewall